# Github different versions of the same file: one for development & one for the repo

Tags: git, github, gitignore, gitattributes

I'am authoring a PHP CMS, that needs an installation to work.
The installation generate a config file.

At localhost i work on an installed version (with a specific config file),
But the users who download the CMS from github would have an empty config file (= uninstalled version).

What I want :
-a specific config file (`config.php`) at localhost (to work on)
-an empty config file (`config.php`) on github (to be downloaded)

I've run across this post : [Can git automatically switch between spaces and tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728)
Not sure if it's really what I'm looking for.
voila.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is not recommended to store configuration files in a repository, mainly because of the reason that the configuration only applies to one environment.

[This](https://gist.github.com/1423106) gist lists some solutions to this problem.

In your case, I would rename the empty config file to something like `config.template.php`, that others can copy to `config.php` and fill in the details. `config.php` is then added to the `.gitignore` file.

That way, the configuration files are only local, and not part of the repository.

Answer (score 2):

A common approach is to [not track](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) the config file at all in git and provide a `config.php.default` file (checked in). Of course you have to tell the users what to do then.